# Calculate $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$ using the definition of integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

I am being asked to calculate the integral $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}~dt$ using the definition of integral (i.e. expressing it as limit of Riemann sums)

Here's what I did:
Let's divide the interval $[1,x]$ into $n$ subintervals of the form $[x_{i},x_{i+1}]$.

Let $x_i=1+\frac{(x-1)i}{n}$ where $i=0,1,2...,n-1. $ be the start points of each subinterval such that $x_0=1$ and $x_n=x$

Let $\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{x-1}{n}$

I defined the integral like this:

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} \, dt&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=o}^{n-1}f(x_{i})\Delta x_{i}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x-1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{(x-1)i}{n}\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

From here, is there a way to go forward without Taylor series?

Comment: So can we assume $x\ge1$, or at least $x>0$?

Comment: Why don't you do some algebra and see if things get clearer? Also, we know the result is $\ln x + C$, so you can manipulate the "inside of the limit" to look more like the Taylor expansion of  $\ln x$.

Comment: Notice that :
$$\ln(1 + x) - \ln (x) \leq \dfrac{1}{x} \leq \ln(x - 1) - \ln (x)$$
And use telescopic sums.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that your markers probably won't like but  I find it entertaining.  *The question is rather silly and deserves a perverse answer.*

Let us "use the definition of the Riemann integral" to find $\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt$  for $x>1$ with $0<x<1$ similar.  The function  $f(t)=\frac1t$ is continuous on $[1,x]$ so the integral exists and (thanks to Cauchy) can be computed as a limit of a sequence of Riemann sums.

[By the way Riemann was unborn at the time that Cauchy used "Riemann sums" and  when Euler did much earlier.]

Having studied some calculus we all know the relation between this integral and logarithms. Some texts define $\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt =\ln x$ while others prove it from some other definition.

Start as you did with an integer $n$ and the points

$$ 1= 1 + a_0 < 1 + a_1 < \dots < 1+a_n =  x$$

where $a_i = \frac{i}n [x-1]$.

On the interval  $[1+ a_0,1+a_1]$  we can choose any associated point $\xi_1$ in that interval .   We use the mean-value theorem to do so:

$$\frac{\ln(1+a_1) - \ln (1+a_0)}{(1+a_1) -  (1+a_0)} = \frac{1}{\xi_1}$$

Do the same on each interval of the partition to get `appropriate' associated points.

This is because $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac 1x.$  On any interval $[a,b] \subset (0,\infty)$ we know that $\frac{\ln b -\ln a}{b-a} = \frac{1}{\xi}$  for some point $a<\xi< b$.

The Riemann sum now is easy to compute:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{\xi_i}[(1+a_i) -  (1+a_{i-1})
=  \sum_{i=1}^n \left[   \ln(1+a_i) - \ln (1+a_{i-1}) \right]
=  \ln x - \ln 1 = \ln x.
$$
Take the limit as $n\to\infty$ [rather easy now] and this proves that
$$ \int_1^x \frac1t\,dt = \ln x  \ \ \ (x>1).$$

---

Even Cauchy knew that you did not have to use the endpoints in computing a 'Riemann sum.'  Riemann knew that any associated points would work for continuous functions and he made it a requirement for 'integrable' functions.

---

---

**P.S.**  The reason I call it *perverse* is that this method can defeat many calculus assignments.

E.g., *Use the definition of integral to compute* $\int_3^7 x^2\,dx$.

Consider $f(x)=x^2$, $F(x)=x^3/3$, $F(7)-F(3)=316/3$.  Take any partition
$3=x_0<x_1< \dots<x_{n-1}<  x_n=7$ and select, by the mean-value theorem, associated points
$\xi_i\in (x_{i-1},x_i)$ so that $F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})=f(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$.
Then, clearly,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})= \sum_{i=1}^n[F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})]=F(7)-F(3) =  316/3$$
for all such Riemann sums.  QED.